# sap.ui.table.Table and count of visible rows

Tags: sapui5

i habe a sap.ui.table.Table that uses a JON data model. a filter is applied to the table to 'hide' unwanted rows. how can i get a count if how many are left showing? thanks. pas.

Comment: In the linked answer, see the section "Using change event from `sap.ui.model.Binding`". The `onChange` handler should be triggered after filtering the table. There, you can call `.getLength()` from the listBinding object to retrieve the number of items left. Should be also working with a JSONModel.

Comment: Solved in https://answers.sap.com/answers/13051308/view.html

Answer (score -2):

Add a updateFinished handler to your table

```
<Table updateFinished="onTableUpdateFinished" ... >
```

and then you can get the row number in the controller like this:

```
onTableUpdateFinished: function (oEvent) {
    var iRows = oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items").getLength();
}
```

Comment: The question author is using `sap.ui.table.Table` which has neither `updateFinished` nor `items`-aggregation.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part, my solution applies only to sap.m.Table.